# Get\Set values from SharePoint 2013 custom fields

Tags: development, client-object-model

How to `Get\Set` values from `ListItem` in SharePoint 2013 custom fields using CSOM and C#?

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to `create/update` item using **CSOM C#**

```
string webUri = "http://servername/sites/demo";
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
        //By Default it will use windows credentials
        //If want to specify credentials use below line
        context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                             "username",
                             "password",
                             "domain");

        Web web = context.Web;

        //Load the web object 
        context.Load(web); 
        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList"); 

        //---------------------Create a new Item----------------//
        ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem newListItem = targetList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
        newListItem["Title"] = "My Item 1";
        newListItem["Comments"] = "Test item";
        newListItem.Update();

        context.Load(newListItem);


       //----------------------get and Update an item--------------//
       ListItem listItem = announcementsList.Items.GetById(1); 

       //Set new value to the Comments field.
       listItem["Comments"] = "Updated test value!!"; 
       listItem.Update(); 

       //---------------------------------------------------//  

       //call Execute Query 
       //to get all the loaded object working
       context.ExecuteQuery();

       Console.WriteLine("Item created!  ID: " + newListItem.Id + "\nTitle: " + newListItem["Title"]);
}
```

You can refer to [My Blog Post](http://blog.sonawanes.com/2015/12/UpdatelistItemUsingCSOM.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is JSOM/Javascript but should be very similar in C# :

```
//Updates a List Item in a given site collection
updateListItem = function(siteURL, listNameSTR, itemID, propertiesOBJ, successFUN) {
    //Get list(item)
    var ctxOBJ = new SP.ClientContext(siteURL);
    var listOBJ = ctxOBJ.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listNameSTR);
    var itemOBJ = listOBJ.getItemById(itemID);

    //Update properties of the item
    for(var propertySTR in propertiesOBJ) {
        itemOBJ.set_item(propertySTR, propertiesOBJ[propertySTR]);
    }

    itemOBJ.update();
    ctxOBJ.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, successFUN), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, function(senderOBJ, argsOBJ){console.log(argsOBJ.get_message() + "\n" + argsOBJ.get_stackTrace());})
    );  
}
```

The properties-Array uses the (real) name of the field as key. btw: There is no big difference between a default field of a list and a custom field.